# Capture Return Value of Method returning base type or derived type

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, return-type

I have a JAVA method which can return an instance of a base class(Say A) OR an instance of the derived class(say B) depending on the Runtime input. ( B derives from A)

Now , in cases when the method returns an object of type 'B' , how do I assign it to a reference of type 'B' ? I can't just assign it to a reference of base type , because I need to use members which are there only in derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can do

```
if (ref instanceof B) {
   B r = (B)ref;
}
```

but fundamentally I think you have a modelling problem. Why do you have a factory (or similar) returning instances of `A` or `B`, and then have to determine what you've been given ?

Perhaps you can have a method common to but implemented differently in both `A` and `B`, and call that, passing in your reference to the caller (originating) class. That way you can invoke a different method depending on both the type calling, and the type being called.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do explicit type casting to make this possible and before doing that check if the class, say `ref` is an instance of subclass `B` by using the keyword `instanceof`.

```
if (ref instanceof B) { //Check if ref is an instance of base class B
    ((B) ref).function();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = yourMethod(input);
if (a instanceof B) {
  B b = (B) a;
  b.subclassmethod();
}
```